# Executing node.js programs

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I am totally new to node.js and trying to run a  program I downloaded from github (as a zip file, instead of git clone).  I installed npm, node and python.  I added python to the path and added the PYTHON variable.  I did an npm install from inside the exploded zip archive.  Reading stackoverflow, I I redid as the install as "npm -g install".

I am trying to run charCryptoExample.js from inside the Samples directory.  When I execute

node Samples\charCryptoExample.js

I get:

```
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './dist/node'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\D\Desktop\node-ld-master\node-ld-master\index.js:1:80)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

I am not sure where to begin solving this; I thought the install created the contents of the dist directories.  Assuming that the code on github is working, are there build process steps that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Yeh, it sounds like you need to build the project.
Have a look in package.json where you should find a "scripts" section. You're looking for a `build` or `compile` script (but could be anything).
If you find one, then you can run it with:

`$ npm run build` or `$ npm run compile`

Failing that, go back to the README of the project where you'll hopefully find build instructions.

Comment: found the repo you're working with.. doesn't look like anything I suggested is going to help..

Comment: actually, `npm run prepublish` might do it.